# Where does intuitionistic predicate logic live in the arithmetical hierarchy?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computability-theory, intuitionism

I started reading Plisko's papers on arithmetic complexity on the arithmetic complexity of constructive logic (see for example [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01247653.pdf) or [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007201000616)). In this context, I started wondering about the following question:

> **Question.** Is intuitionistic first-order logic $\Pi_2$-complete?

I would also be interested in a reference. My knowledge on the arithmetic hierarchy is at the moment only very shallow, so maybe I am just not seeing that this question has a trivial answer.

Comment: Intuitionstic first-order logic is recursively axiomatized, and therefore $\Sigma_1$. (It is in fact $\Sigma_1$-complete.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Oh, of course, thank you!

Comment: It looks like Plisko has some unusual definitions. The complexity Plisko measures is not the set of $T$-provable statements but "$T$-valid" statements, meaning "each of its closed arithmetic instances is in $T$". If this means what I think it does then I think intuitionistic first-order logic is $\Pi_2$-complete, but I have no way of knowing whether I'm right without wading through Plisko's definitions.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais No, even under that definition, the set of valid statements of intuitionistic first-order logic is just the usual intuitionistic first-order logic. In fact, this is even true of HA-valid statements: see Leivant, Absoluteness of intuitionistic logic.